# What's the best way to secure data between an PHP webservice and a Android/Java application

Tags: java, php, android

And by that i don't mean using HTTPS, but data encryption.

Is there a nice encryption method that i can use in PHP to encrypt the data and decrypt in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it can be decrypted on the client side it would get decrypted on the man in the middle side wouldn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES-256 is the same in both Java as PHP: the algorithm itself is naturally language agnostic, so you can just pick one. That said, if you were to use HTTPS, the data would be encrypted either way, so perhaps you're overcomplicating things? Is the data *that* important and privacy-sensitive?

Comment: Thanks Berry, Ill look into the AES-265 algorithms :-)

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) **does** data encryption. If you're planning to negotiate the encryption without any pre-shared keys then HTTPS is probably one of your best options. It's not trivial to get encryption done in a proper way, so it's usually best to leverage existing implementations.

If you are planning on using a shared key that the client and server each know about, then you do likely want to use [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). For the Java side see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520640/encrypting-and-decrypting-using-java/5520786#5520786). You'll have to search around for the PHP side. Be sure to follow all of the best practices if you're aiming for security.