# How to fix the NoSuchAlgorithmException in Java when using Blowfish?

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

So I'm writing a program to encrypt and decrypt text files but I seem to be always getting this error when I use an encrypthion other than "Blowfish" (e.g. "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding"). The excepthiong I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at Encryptor.<init>(Encryptor.java:87)
    at Encryptor.main(Encryptor.java:30)
```

A portion of my code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryptor2 {
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    private SecretKeySpec keySpec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Encryptor2 e = new Encryptor2(
                "averylongtext!@$@#$#@$#*&(*&}{23432432432dsfsdf");
        String enc = e.encrypt("john doe");
        String dec = e.decrypt(enc);
    }

    public Encryptor2(String pass) throws Exception {
        // setup AES cipher in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // setup an IV (initialization vector) that should be
        // randomly generated for each input that's encrypted
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // hash keyString with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(pass.getBytes());
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, key, 0, key.length);
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

    public String encrypt(String original) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(original.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("encrypted: `" + new String(encrypted) + "`");
        return new String(encrypted);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("decrypted: `" + new String(decrypted, "UTF-8")
                + "`");
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

But now it fails with `Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The additional parameters that you're specifying with the algorithm are meant for `Cipher`. For `KeyGenerator` and `SecretKeySpec` you only specify the algorithm. The other parameters are for the cipher mode of operation and padding to be used. For example, if you're using Blowfish in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding you want:

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

See [Encrypting and Decrypting Using Java: Unable to get same output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520640/encrypting-and-decrypting-using-java/5520786#5520786) for an example. It uses the same mode and padding as you have. The only difference is that uses AES instead of Blowfish, however it works exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear I will update my question with more code because I do just that.

Comment: @Tamer: "Not clear" is one thing - but you've posted entirely clear code which is in no way the same as what WhiteFang34 has posted. Did you post your real code or not?

Comment: You need to specify just `"Blowfish"`. You'll only pass `"Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` to `Cipher.getInstance()`.

Comment: Ahh. Ok, I apologize I completely misunderstood your answer and I understand what I have to do now. I have tried it and it works but now I'm getting another exception: `Parameters missing` but this is another issue I'll look into it. Thanks very much!

Comment: I added a link to an example with details that uses CBC. You need to specify an IV (initialization vector) for that mode.

Comment: I'm stuck with `Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher` when I tried to modulate the code you provided in the link and using Blowfish.

Comment: Ah, I updated the other answer with a fix. The block size is different for Blowfish so the IV has to be 8 bytes instead of 16. I changed the example to get the block size from the cipher so it works for AES and Blowfish.