# Encryption using Blowfish in CBC mode in Java

Tags: java, encryption, key, blowfish

I need to encrypt a specific String using Blowfish encryption in CBC mode with no padding in Java. I have done some research and I found this question: [encrypting and decrypting using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520640/encrypting-and-decrypting-using-java/5520786#5520786).

I want to know how I could use a basic String as a key in the init method of the Cipher object. In the example, the keySpec is not a String but a String encrypted with SHA-256.

In the example:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
```

where `keySpec` is a `SecretKeySpec` object

What I need:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyString, ivSpec);
```

where `keyString` is a `String` object

I know that using a basic String is less secure than auto-generate one. But do you know how I could use a String as a key?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(charset), "Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
```

Comment: I tried but I have an error: "Input length not multiple of 8 bytes" when I do:
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(token.getBytes());

The token length need to be a multiple of 8 bytes?

Comment: I'm no Blowfish expert and the internet is on strike today, so i can't quickly become one, but afaik Blowfish needs a key of at least 32 bits. The 8 bytes minimum requirement is fairly common, though. May i ask why you need to use such a short key?

Comment: I have found my error. The String I try to encrypt contains 22 characters and its length should be a multiple of 8. So I think I have to use a padding. Which one should I use? (I have to use the same as the standard padding in PERL)

Comment: I am quite sure that the main problem is not the padding but the SecretKey generated. I really need to use the String keyString for the encryption. Do you know I could use this String and not the SecretKey anymore?

Comment: You can never *directly* use the key string as the blowfish algorithm is only specified on bytes. So, as you may have already found out, you need to *encode* the string to X bytes, and then pad it to Y bytes, where Y = keysize in bytes. If you need to talk somebody you need the encoding and padding used, although trying "UTF-8 as encoding and 00h padding at the right would probably be most common (using a password as key is not smart at all, you should always use a key derivation mechanism, e.g. PBKDF2).

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. I know it's not secure but I have to use a password as key to be compatible with another algorithm.

Comment: How dows this other algorithm handle issues like encoding and short keys?

Comment: BTW, the standard padding in Perl::Crypt is afaik PKCS#5. So you should use `Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`. I tried that here and i'm not getting the "Input length not multiple of 8 bytes" exception you saw.